# How do i sync Google Keep via Bluetooth/wifi without internet connection?

Tags: applications, 4.1-jelly-bean, google, google-keep

I use Google Keep on my Android as well as Ubuntu, living in a remote area of a developing nation, internet outages are common. So i need to sync my notes on google keep with my android, is it possible? If not what are a few alternatives that is recommended that syncs notes via Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Bluetooth Chat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jastrzab.serwer.bluetooth) to copy, paste and send notes through Bluetooth. Google Keep doesn't have any functionality to share notes without internet.

You can also setup a network drive and save your notes as a `.txt` on anything connected to your Wi-Fi without internet. That's a bit harder to do though.